# Solving a constraint for an optimal wage offer.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Having trouble solving for a constraint when there is two different variables within the equation.

eg. **wg** represents wage with a good outcome , and **wb** represents wage with a bad outcome. The constraint asks for expected wage needed to satisfy a good outcome in the equation:

$$ 0.8(wg -10000) + 0.2(wb-10000) >= 20000, and, $$

$$ 0.8(wg -10000) + 0.2(wb-10000) >= 0.3wg - 0.7wb $$

The answer for **wg** is 34000 and **wb**  is 14000, but I'm finding it difficult to isolate the **wg**.

Answer (score 0):

When you simplify both constraints, you get
$$
0.8 w_g+0.2w_b \ge 20000+8000+2000 = 30000\\
0.5 w_g+0.9w_b \ge 0 + 8000 + 2000 = 10000
$$
So you want to solve
$$
\begin{split}
4 w_g+1w_b = 150000\\
5 w_g+9w_b = 100000
\end{split}
$$
and subtracting $9$ times the first equation from the second yields
$$
(5-4\cdot 9)w_g = (1-1.5\cdot9)\times 10^5
$$